# Preventing javascript errors on "stopping" my code

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to console(.)error an error without it stopping the code. Like a global try/catch

Comment: `console.error` doesn't stop code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.onerror` event handler as a global event handler and write something like:

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(error, url, lineNumber) {
  logger("error has occured = " + error);
  return false;
}
```

you can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: This is for web.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to continue, there's try-catch-finally:

```
try {
  tryCode - Block of code to try
}
catch(err) {
  catchCode - Block of code to handle errors
}
finally {
  finallyCode - Block of code to be executed regardless of the try / catch result
}
```